# How to find the JNDI look-up name of EJB programmatically?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, jndi, ejb-3.1

I am using EJB 3.1 in my application.

I want to send one EJB's JNDI look-up name in my application to another application so that it can use that at run time & communicate with my EJB. As the look-up name depends upon the name of the ear files deployed on the EJB container & the name of these ear files will be changing every time any changes are done in my application.

What is the procedure of finding out the look-up name of the any EJB programmatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, I wouldn't recommend that approach. Why don't you fix JNDI names of your EJBs?

That said, you can call a method `InitialContext#list` to iterate through the JNDI tree and find out the name of your EJB. There is a nice code example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324937/code-to-list-all-the-entries-in-jndi-on-remote-machine), so I won't repeat it. An important note - calling `ctx.list("")` will only give you first level of JNDI tree, so you will have to call that method recursively in order to obtain EJB names. Hint: EJBs are usually deployed under branch **ejb**.

See also:

- [InitialContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html)