# Geronimo 3: EJB lookup resulting in NamingException

Tags: java, ejb, jndi, openejb, geronimo

I've just created a simple Enterprise Application Project in Eclipse with web module and EJB3 module.

This is my **EJB**:

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean implements MyBeanRemote {
    public String getGreeting(){return "Hello World!";}
}
```

This is my **Remote Business Interface**:

```
@Remote
public interface MyBeanRemote {
    String getGreeting();
}
```

This is my **Servlet**:

```
@WebServlet("/MyServlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        MyBeanRemote myBean = null;

        try {
            myBean=(MyBeanRemote) new InitialContext().lookup("XXX");                //1
        } catch (NamingException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        response.getWriter().append(myBean.getGreeting());
    }
}
```

Bean injection works like a charm, but I'm not being able to successfully perform a JDNI lookup: what should be inserted at line `//1` instead of `XXX`? I've tried any possible combination (well, clearly missing the right one...)

As far as I understand, Geronimo uses OpenEJB to map name to resources, and [at this page](http://openejb.apache.org/jndi-names.html) you can read that

> The default JNDI name is in the following format: `{deploymentId}{interfaceType.annotationName}`

so I thought it was just `MyBeanRemote`, but that's not working... What am I missing? I've spent my last hours with unsuccessful attempts and reading similar answers here on SO.

This is my **openejb.jar.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ejb:openejb-jar xmlns:app="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/j2ee/application-2.0" xmlns:bp="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0" xmlns:client="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/j2ee/application-client-2.0" xmlns:conn="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/j2ee/connector-1.2" xmlns:dep="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/deployment-1.2" xmlns:ejb="http://openejb.apache.org/xml/ns/openejb-jar-2.2" xmlns:jaspi="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/geronimo-jaspi" xmlns:log="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/loginconfig-2.0" xmlns:name="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/naming-1.2" xmlns:pers="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:pkgen="http://openejb.apache.org/xml/ns/pkgen-2.1" xmlns:sec="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/security-2.0" xmlns:web="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/j2ee/web-2.0.1">
    <dep:environment>
        <dep:moduleId>
            <dep:groupId>default</dep:groupId>
            <dep:artifactId>MyProjectEJB</dep:artifactId>
            <dep:version>1.0</dep:version>
            <dep:type>car</dep:type>
        </dep:moduleId>
    </dep:environment>
</ejb:openejb-jar>
```

as created by the wizard.

Comment: you can elist the content of your jndi context Context.list(""); this will enlist the first level of the tree you can start from there going deeper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user *achabahe* [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443981/geronimo-3-ejb-lookup-resulting-in-namingexception#comments-35443981), and with the help of these [question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324937/code-to-list-all-the-entries-in-jndi-on-remote-machine), I printed my whole JNDI tree:

```
String getJNDITree() {
    Context context=null;
    try {
        context = new InitialContext();
    } catch (NamingException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}

    List<String>roots=Arrays.asList("java:comp","java:module","java:app","java:global");

    StringBuilder tree=new StringBuilder();
    for(String root:roots)
        recursiveDeepVisit(context,root,"",tree);   

    return tree.toString()+"\n";
}

void recursiveDeepVisit(Context context,String path,String prefix,StringBuilder tree){
    tree.append("\n"+prefix+path);
    try {
        NamingEnumeration<NameClassPair> list = context.list(path);
        while (list.hasMore()) {
            String innerPath = path+"/"+list.next().getName();
            recursiveDeepVisit(context, innerPath, "    "+prefix,tree);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

getting this output

```
java:
    java:app
        java:app/env
        java:app/MyProjectEJB
            java:app/MyProjectEJB/MyBean!com.dev.bean.MyBeanRemote
            java:app/MyProjectEJB/MyBean
        java:app/AppName
    java:comp
        java:comp/UserTransaction
        java:comp/HandleDelegate
        java:comp/ValidatorFactory
        java:comp/TransactionManager
        java:comp/Bundle
        java:comp/TransactionSynchronizationRegistry
        java:comp/env
        java:comp/ORB
        java:comp/Validator
        java:comp/BundleContext
    java:TransactionManager
    java:TransactionSynchronizationRegistry
    java:module
        java:module/ModuleName
        java:module/env
    java:global
        java:global/MyProject
            java:global/MyProject/MyProjectEJB
                java:global/MyProject/MyProjectEJB/MyBean!com.dev.bean.MyBeanRemote
                java:global/MyProject/MyProjectEJB/MyBean
        java:global/geronimo-mejb-3.0.1
            java:global/geronimo-mejb-3.0.1/MEJB
            java:global/geronimo-mejb-3.0.1/ejb
                java:global/geronimo-mejb-3.0.1/ejb/mgmt
                    java:global/geronimo-mejb-3.0.1/ejb/mgmt/MEJB
                    java:global/geronimo-mejb-3.0.1/ejb/mgmt/MEJB!javax.management.j2ee.ManagementHome
            java:global/geronimo-mejb-3.0.1/MEJB!javax.management.j2ee.ManagementHome
        java:global/env
```

It turns out that

```
MyBeanRemote myBean=(MyBeanRemote) new InitialContext().lookup("java:app/MyProjectEJB/MyBean!com.dev.bean.MyBeanRemote");
```

is the solution I was looking for.