# Unable to bind JMS resources with Openliberty

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, open-liberty

I am doing my first steps with Jakarta Messaging on OpenLiberty. A simple sender and receiver "test". But I am having troubles binding the JNDI resources.

This is my `server.xml` config:

```xml
...
    <featureManager>
        <feature>webProfile-9.1</feature>
        <feature>mail-2.0</feature>
        <feature>concurrent-2.0</feature>
        <feature>messaging-3.0</feature>
    </featureManager>
...
    <messagingEngine>
        <queue id="SIMPLE_QUEUE"/>
    </messagingEngine>

    <jmsQueueConnectionFactory jndiName="jms/JmsFactory">
        <properties.wasJms />
    </jmsQueueConnectionFactory>

    <jmsQueue id="jms/JmsQueue" jndiName="jms/JmsQueue">
        <properties.wasJms queueName="SIMPLE_QUEUE"/>
    </jmsQueue>

    <jmsActivationSpec id="jms/Reader">
        <properties.wasJms destinationRef="jms/JmsQueue"/>
    </jmsActivationSpec>
...
```

This is my sender

```java
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import jakarta.annotation.Resource;
import jakarta.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Named;
import jakarta.jms.*;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Sender implements Serializable {
    @Resource(lookup = "jms/JmsQueue")
    private Queue queue;

    @Resource(lookup = "jms/JmsFactory")
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    private Connection connection;
    private Session session;
    private MessageProducer producer;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        try {
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            session = connection.createSession();
            producer = session.createProducer(queue);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void send() {
        try {
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
            message.setText("Hello world");
            producer.send(message);
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

However the line `connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();` throws a nullpointer exception. I tried [printing the JNDI bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37021007), but the JMS stuff is missing.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Edit:

Due to the tip from @Gas, adding `<feature>messagingServer-3.0</feature>` and `<feature>messagingClient-3.0</feature>` solved the issue and the JMS components appear in JNDI.

Comment: Didnt test it, but I think you are missing jms provider. In case of OpenLiberty built in one you have to add `<feature>messagingServer-3.0</feature>`  to server.xml.

Comment: I tried it, but it does not work either.

Comment: FYI, you're allowed to post the answer to your own question on StackOverflow.  (Or you could give Gas a chance to post and if you don't see anything then you could go ahead and post it.)

Comment: @kanonroald Feel free to describe the answer. My comment was just a hint ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the tip of @Gas, adding

```
...
    <feature>messagingServer-3.0</feature>
    <feature>messagingClient-3.0</feature> 
...
```

solved the issue and the JMS components appear in JNDI.

Comment: If this is the correct answer please mark it as such to help other users who encounter this same issue in the future. Thanks!